# Symfony, FOSUserBundle: Retrieve all static and dynamic roles

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Using FOSUserBundle I have two places where I can define user roles: `security.yml` (static) and per `roles` property in the User-Entity (DB, dynamic). How can I retrieve a complete list of *all* roles for a user (also the inherited)?

Example

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_SUPERADMIN:  [ROLE_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPERDUPERADMIN: [ROLE_SUPERADMIN]
```

User-Roles (Entity):
`[ROLE_BOARDMODERATOR, ROLE_CHATMODEARTOR, ROLE_ADMIN]`.

The endresult would have to be something like:
`[ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_BOARDMODERATOR, ROLE_CHATMODERATOR]`

Answer (score 2):

Inspecting the security panel from Symfony Profiler I worked out following solution (Symfony 3):

```
//retrieve dynamic roles and the last static role
$endRoles = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getRoles();
//add all inherited roles
$allRoles = array_unique($this->get('security.role_hierarchy')->getReachableRoles($endRoles), SORT_REGULAR);
```